# Can decltype make less recompilation

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, decltype

I'm working on a cpp project, let's say there is such a piece of code:

```
// header1.h
struct Test {
    int a;
    bool func(int b) { return a < b; }
};

// header2.h
#include "header1.h"
void myfunc(int aa) {
    Test t;
    t.a = aa;
    bool res = t.func(3);
    // something else
}

// header3.h
#include "header1.h"
void myfunc(decltype(Test::a) aa) {   // CHANGED HERE
    Test t;
    t.a = aa;
    bool res = t.func(3);
    // something else
}
```

I was always coding like `headedr2.h`. But today, I got such a case, where the type of `Test::a` in the `header1.h` may change into `uint8_t`, `int32_t` etc in the future. If it changes, the `header2.h` should be changed too. (I don't want to make any implicit-conversion.)

That means, if `header1.h` changes, I have to change `header2.h`, as a result, all of files including `header2.h` have to be recompiled.

Now, I'm thinking if it is possible to use `decltype` just like `header3.h` to avoid recompilation. In other words, I'm asking if I code `header3.h` instead of `header2.h`, is it possible to avoid recompilation of the files which included `header3.h` after changing the type of `Test::a` in `header1.h`?

Comment: Once you change the type of a class member variable, you basically need to recompile everything that uses this class. Such a change generally changes the storage requirements for objects (byte size, alignment, padding, etc.). In your case, without recompilation, `t` variable inside `myfunc` could have incorrect storage allocated.

Comment: Relevant article: [20 ABI (Application Binary Interface) breaking changes every C++ developer should know](https://www.acodersjourney.com/20-abi-breaking-changes/).

Comment: Since `header2.h` includes `header1.h`, all compilation units that include `header2.h` will need to be recompiled anyway when `header1.h` changes.   The value of using `decltype` in `header2.h` is that you don't need to edit `header2.h` if `header1.h` changes (and don't run the risk - e.g. failed compilation - of forgetting to make that change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you change `header1.h` you have to recompile everything that includes `header1.h`.

The reason is: how could the compiler generate the code for `myfunc` without knowing the type of its argument, or without knowing the `Test` type that you use inside `myfunc`?

If you change the `struct Test`, altering the type of its members, all the code generated using an outdated declaration of `Test` is likely to fail to compile at the linking stage, or it could have an unpredictable behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

From compilation, all files which includes `"header1"` should be recompiled.

Usage of `decltype(Test::a)` requires the `#include` whereas using `int` directly doesn't (definition needs it anyway but could be in cpp).

Using `decltype(Test::a)` would avoid to have to update code at several places though.

It might make sense to have alias for `decltype(Test::a)` such as

```
struct Test {
    using type_a = int;
    type_a a;
    bool func(type_a b) const { return a < b; }
};
```

and use `Test::type_a` which seems more idiomatic.